# Parse/AngularJS - Input data with user id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, database, parse-platform

I'm working on a Parse App with AngularJS, and reworking a controller to point to the logged in user when posting. On my database table, I've set a column "author" to point to the users. I made a separate service.js file which I call with Squeeg. When I click create, it does not input the data with the user.id. It works fine without it. How would I fix this to ensure that the user objectId is a part of the data is added to the database?

```
$scope.create=function(){
    var user = Parse.User.current(); 
    console.log(user.id); 

    Squeeg.create({ author:user.id, eventname:$scope.events.title, eventDescription:$scope.events.description}).success(function(data){
       alert("done");
    });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `author: user`?

Comment: Tried that out, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since I need 50 reputation to comment, this needs to be asked here, have you  accessed authfactory/authserverice to get the current user from there? Assuming you have login?

Then in authFactory you could have something like this.

```
app.factory('authFactory', ['$http', '$window', function ($http, $window) {
    var authFactory = {};

    authFactory.logIn = function (user) {
        return $http.post('/login', user).success(function (data) {
            authFactory.saveToken(data.token);
        });
    };

    authFactory.saveToken = function (token) {
        $window.localStorage['appToken'] = token;
    };

    authFactory.getToken = function () {
        return $window.localStorage['appToken'];
    };

    authFactory.logOut = function () {
        $window.localStorage.removeItem('appToken');
    };


    authFactory.currentUser = function () {
        if(authFactory.isLoggedIn()){
            var token = authFactory.getToken();
            var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

            return payload.username; // or return payload.id ..... / return payload 
        }
    };

    authFactory.isLoggedIn = function () {
        var token = authFactory.getToken();

        if(token){
            var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob( token.split('.')[1]) );

            return payload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    return authFactory;
}]);
```

Then all you need to do is binding it with your controller to access it.

```
app.controller('AnyCtrl', ['$scope', 'authFactory',
    function ($scope, authFactory) {

        $scope.currentUser = authFactory.currentUser;
    }
]);
```